# Hierarchical Cluster Analysis

Tags: hierarchical-clustering

I came across answers to many of questions about Cluster Analysis in this platform. One area I still need clarification has to do with missing cases. I obtained DHS data and extracted sub-regional variables that my study considered useful. I further constructed variables from the data. I concern I have now is, after attempting Hierarchical Cluster Analysis on three surveys, missen cases are 181 (60%), 665(46%) and 534(43%) respectively. As a new person doing statistical analysis, especially the HCA, I need advice on addressing missing cases.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of my questions, similar to yours got answered by this article.

http://www.econ.upf.edu/~michael/stanford/maeb7.pdf.

This article gives a detailed explaination on Hirearchical Cluster Analysis.

Comment: answers should provide context to links, providing a summary of the content there in case a link gets broken (ideally answers should be as self contained as possible)